# Does pax logging support standard osgi log service api

Tags: logging, osgi, pax

I configured pax logging on my osgi runtime and test standard osgi log service but the logging was not recorded. Anyway all other logging API's seems to be working as [2] expected. Do I miss anything ?

```
LogService logService;

public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {

    ServiceReference ref = bundleContext.getServiceReference(LogService.class.getName());
    if (ref != null)
    {
        logService = (LogService) bundleContext.getService(ref);
        logService.log(LogService.LOG_INFO, " -----------  Testing OSGI logging on bundle start  -------------------- ");
}
```

[1] https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxlogging/Installation

[2] https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxlogging/Pax+Logging

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is a classic mistake with OSGi: you expect the LogService to be available at start up time. If it is delayed, you end up having a `null` reference and not logging anything.

Try using a standard method of injecting services when they get published, like the [Declarative Services component model](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Declarative_Services).

A good tutorial can be found [on the IBM Infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_declare_services_ds.html).